# How to call MySQL stored procedure with OUT parameter in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Does anybody know how to call MySQL stored procedure with OUT parameter in Laravel?

Let’s say I have:

```
DB::statement('CALL sp_user_add(:name, :email, :password, :key, @res, @id);',
    array(
        $name,
        $email,
        $password,
        $key
    )
);
```

How to get values of `@res` and `@id`?

Comment: Maybe you get the values returned if you use `DB::select()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm getting my information from http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedures-return-multiple-values/ and this is untested, but it looks as though you will need to issue an additional statement to grab those values...

Try adding this after...

```
$results = DB::select('select @res as res, @id as id');
```

And then results are in $results[0]->res and $results[0]->id.

Comment: Does it need select?  I thought Laravel puts that in automatically when using `select()`.

Comment: Yep! Thank you!
You are almost right. You’ve simply forgotten ‘select’ in your query.